# How to get SGDClassifier to reflect uncertainty

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How do you get [sklearn's `SGDClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) to show uncertainty in its predictions?

I'm trying to confirm that `SGDClassifier` will will report a probability of 50% on input data that does not strictly correspond to any label. However, I'm finding the classifier is 100% certain all the time.

I'm testing this with the following script:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

c = SGDClassifier(loss="log")
#c = SGDClassifier(loss="modified_huber")

X = [
    # always -1
    [1,0,0],
    [1,0,0],
    [1,0,0],
    [1,0,0],

    # always +1
    [0,0,1],
    [0,0,1],
    [0,0,1],
    [0,0,1],

    # uncertain
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1,0],
]
y = [
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
    +1,
    +1,
    +1,
    +1,

    -1,
    +1,
    -1,
    +1,
    -1,
    +1,
    -1,
    +1,
]

def lookup_prob_class(c, dist):
    a = sorted(zip(dist, c.classes_))
    best_prob, best_class = a[-1]
    return best_prob, best_class

c.fit(X, y)

probs = c.predict_proba(X)
print 'probs:'
for dist, true_value in zip(probs, y):
    prob, value = lookup_prob_class(c, dist)
    print '%.02f'%prob, value, true_value
```

As you can see, my training data always associates -1 with the input data [1,0,0], +1 with [0,0,1] and 50/50 for [0,1,0].

Therefore, I would expect the result from `predict_proba()` to return 0.5 for the input [0,1,0]. But instead, it reports a probability of 100%. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Interestingly, swapping out `SGDClassifier` for [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) or [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) does produce the output I expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does show some uncertainty:

```
>>> c.predict_proba(X)
array([[  9.97254333e-01,   2.74566740e-03],
       [  9.97254333e-01,   2.74566740e-03],
       [  9.97254333e-01,   2.74566740e-03],
       [  9.97254333e-01,   2.74566740e-03],
       [  1.61231111e-06,   9.99998388e-01],
       [  1.61231111e-06,   9.99998388e-01],
       [  1.61231111e-06,   9.99998388e-01],
       [  1.61231111e-06,   9.99998388e-01],
       [  1.24171982e-04,   9.99875828e-01],
       [  1.24171982e-04,   9.99875828e-01],
       [  1.24171982e-04,   9.99875828e-01],
       [  1.24171982e-04,   9.99875828e-01],
       [  1.24171982e-04,   9.99875828e-01],
       [  1.24171982e-04,   9.99875828e-01],
       [  1.24171982e-04,   9.99875828e-01],
       [  1.24171982e-04,   9.99875828e-01]])
```

If you want the model to be more uncertain, you have to regularize it more strongly. That's done by tweaking the `alpha` parameter:

```
>>> c = SGDClassifier(loss="log", alpha=1)
>>> c.fit(X, y)
SGDClassifier(alpha=1, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.0,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='optimal',
       loss='log', n_iter=5, n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', power_t=0.5,
       random_state=None, shuffle=False, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
>>> c.predict_proba(X)
array([[ 0.58782817,  0.41217183],
       [ 0.58782817,  0.41217183],
       [ 0.58782817,  0.41217183],
       [ 0.58782817,  0.41217183],
       [ 0.53000442,  0.46999558],
       [ 0.53000442,  0.46999558],
       [ 0.53000442,  0.46999558],
       [ 0.53000442,  0.46999558],
       [ 0.55579239,  0.44420761],
       [ 0.55579239,  0.44420761],
       [ 0.55579239,  0.44420761],
       [ 0.55579239,  0.44420761],
       [ 0.55579239,  0.44420761],
       [ 0.55579239,  0.44420761],
       [ 0.55579239,  0.44420761],
       [ 0.55579239,  0.44420761]])
```

`alpha` is a penalty on high feature weights, so the higher `alpha`, the less the weights are allowed to grow, the less extreme the linear model value become and the closer the logistic probability estimates get to ½. Usually, this parameter is tuned using cross-validation.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. You've just changed it from returning 100% certainty for everything, to returning 50% certainty for everything. It should only show 50% for the sample inputs that half correspond to +1 and half correspond to -1. It should still show 100%  for the inputs that always correspond to a specific label.

Comment: Oh, I see, as the alpha goes to infinity, all probabilities become 0.5, and as alpha does to zero, all probabilities become 1.0. The sweet spot for me seems to be an alpha of 0.01. It doesn't quite get the exact 50%/100% probabilities I want, but it's close enough. Thanks.